# Need some advice on using PAMIE

Tags: python-3.x, pamie

I am currently using Python 3.2. I am planning to use PAMIE to simulate some webpages. Will that work? Is PAMIE the best way to simulate webpages with Python? If yes, What else do I need to run PAMIE? I don't see a lot of tutorials/Online help on PAMIE. Is it because it's not used widely? Please advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.A.M.I.E. is not for simulating webpages, but for automating access to them. Since it requires Internet Explorer I would say that it almost per definition is not the best way to do it. It certainly can not be used much, and this is the first time I've heard of it after 10 years of Python web development.

A much more commonly used solution is [Webdriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html), which also supports both IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Another solution, if you don't need Javascript support, is to use [mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). This doesn't control a web browser, but is an implementation of a "headless" web browser and can be good for making test suites.